# Why does scipy.stats.nanmean give different result from numpy.nansum?

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, scipy, floating-point-precision

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy import stats
>>> a = np.r_[1., 2., np.nan, 4., 5.]
>>> stats.nanmean(a)
2.9999999999999996
>>> np.nansum(a)/np.sum(~np.isnan(a))
3.0
```

I'm aware of the limitation of floating point representation. Just curious why the more clumsy expression seems to give "better" result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, here is `scipy.nanmean()` so that we know what we're comparing to:

```
def nanmean(x, axis=0):
    x, axis = _chk_asarray(x,axis)
    x = x.copy()
    Norig = x.shape[axis]
    factor = 1.0-np.sum(np.isnan(x),axis)*1.0/Norig

    x[np.isnan(x)] = 0
    return np.mean(x,axis)/factor
```

Mathematically, the two methods are equivalent. Numerically, they are different.

Your method involves a single division, and it so happens that:

- the numerator (`1. + 2. + 4. + 5.`) can be represented exactly as a `float`; and
- the denominator (`4.`) is a power of two.

This means that the result of the division is exact, `3.`.

`stats.nanmean()` involves first computing the mean of `[1., 2., 0., 4., 5.]`, and then adjusting it to account for `NaNs`. As it happens, this mean (`2.4`) cannot be represented exactly as a `float`, so from this point on the computation is inexact.

I haven't given it a lot of thought, but it may be possible to construct an example where the roles would be reversed, and `stats.nanmean()` would give a more accurate result than the other method.

What surprises me is that `stats.nanmean()` doesn't simply do something like:

```
In [6]: np.mean(np.ma.MaskedArray(a, np.isnan(a)))
Out[6]: 3.0
```

This seems to me to be a superior approach to what it does currently.

Comment: Indeed, `b = np.r_[1., 2., np.nan, 4., 8.]` would be more friendly for `np.mean`, keeping everything else constant. But I found it difficult to construct a reversed example:)

Comment: Masked arrays are slow (implemented in pure Python) so I guess that what the questioner proposed (`np.nansum(a)/np.sum(~np.isnan(a))` actually is faster than `np.mean(np.ma.MaskedArray(a, np.isnan(a)))`. Someone should try :)

Comment: So yeah, with a long one-dimensional array `dat`, `np.nansum(dat) / np.sum(~np.isnan(dat))` executes 10 % faster than `np.mean(np.ma.masked_array(dat, np.isnan(dat)))`. Bottleneck's nanmean, however, executes 10 times as fast.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the code of `stats.nanmean`:

```
x, axis = _chk_asarray(x,axis)
x = x.copy()
Norig = x.shape[axis]
factor = 1.0-np.sum(np.isnan(x),axis)*1.0/Norig
x[np.isnan(x)] = 0
return np.mean(x,axis)/factor
```

I believe it has something to do with the `1.0 - np.sum`, a substraction of the sum.

Answer (score 1):

As @eumiro mentioned, stats.nanmean calculated the mean in a circumlocutions way different from the straightforward one liner way you did

From the same reference code,

`np.sum(np.isnan(x),axis)` returns `numpy.int32` which when multiplied by * `1.0`, results a floating point approximation as opposed to what it would have got when the result would have been integer resulting in a difference in result

```
>>> numpy.int32(1)*1.0/5
0.20000000000000001
>>> int(numpy.int32(1))*1.0/5
0.2
>>> type(np.sum(np.isnan(x),axis))
<type 'numpy.int32'>
```

Comment: I think you pointed out another interesting behavior of numpy: `a = np.int_(1)/5.0; np.float_(a) -> 0.20000000000000001; float(a) -> 0.2`