# Float Approximation when using numpy.int32

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, int

Answering one question [Why does scipy.stats.nanmean give different result from numpy.nansum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475485/why-does-scipy-stats-nanmean-give-different-result-from-numpy-nansum), I realized, multiplying `numpy.int32` by a `float` results in different float result compared to a Python POD `int` with a `float`.

Is there a reason to cause a float approximation when using `numpy.int32`

```
>>> numpy.int32(1) * 0.2
0.20000000000000001
>>> 1 * 0.2
0.2
```

Comment: While it doesn't answer the question, it appears you are concerned about the precision of your output, you may want to mix similar types and then perform operations, like numpy.float32(1)*numpy.float32(0.2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two expressions give results that are identical in value but have different types:

```
In [17]: numpy.int32(1) * 0.2 == 1 * 0.2
Out[17]: True

In [18]: type(numpy.int32(1) * 0.2)
Out[18]: numpy.float64

In [19]: type(1 * 0.2)
Out[19]: float
```

The different output is purely due to the difference in default formatting between `numpy.float64` and `float`.

If we reverse the types, the output also reverses:

```
In [12]: float(numpy.int32(1) * 0.2)
Out[12]: 0.2

In [13]: numpy.float64(1 * 0.2)
Out[13]: 0.20000000000000001
```

It's purely a display issue. There is no numerical difference here.

Comment: Isn't it because `0.20000000000000001 == 0.2`
is `True`. The difference as you see is noticeable in the linked question.

Comment: If `0.20000000000000001` and `0.2` compare equal (which they do), this means they have identical 64-bit IEEE 754 representation after rounding, which means they are represented by exactly the same floating-point number. There is no numerical difference here, it's a red herring.